# multiprocessing run process in new console python to get input for each process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to run multiple instance of the same class at the same time. Each instance have a method which require an input.

I have a module that requires to run in different places at the same time. These modules runs independent from each other. I should be able to signal the instance of the module from the control(main) module. So i tried to do this with multi threading but i can't get input at the same time. Code below returns a EOF error.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Concurrent():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myMethod(self):
        value = input("Enter input : ")


num = int(input("Enter number of process to run : "))

obj_arr=[]
for i in range(num):
    obj = Concurrent()
    obj_arr.append(obj)

def func(obj):
    obj.myMethod()

ps = []
for obj in obj_arr:
    p = mp.Process(target = func,args = (obj,))
    ps.append(p)

[x.start() for x in ps]
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in 
 _bootstrap
    self.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in 
run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "concurrent.py", line 21, in func
    obj.stressCPU()
  File "concurrent.py", line 10, in stressCPU
    value = input("Enter input : ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are trying to implement a MP pool that will run a function.
Please refer to:https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html